# Mysql service stops everyday at 6AM in EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

In my AWS server, WordPress is present along with MySQL. And MySQL server stopping automatically by itself every 6 AM (most of the time). Can anyone suggest me a solution?

I am providing the log while stopping.

**sudo tail -100 /var/log/mysqld.log**

```
Version: '5.6.47'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 10.0M
InnoDB: mmap(10731520 bytes) failed; errno 12
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [ERROR] Aborting

2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Binlog end
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2020-03-14 00:32:04 4015 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql56/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: this error mean that you have no enough memory, check if you have swap enabled `free -m`

Comment: Additional information request.AWS model used, 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
AND Optional very helpful information - request through 
AWS support team, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: **free -m** response

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           985        749        236          0         19        131
-/+ buffers/cache:        598        386
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Comment: @christyram99 I take it this means you have 985M total RAM on this AWS service. Which AWS service are you signed up for? Will still try to assist if you can post any of above information requested. – Wilson Hauck 15 hours ago

Comment: Yeah, I will add it

Comment: @christyram99  Please post a comment after adding with reference to me.  I will be notified by Stackoverflow.com if you will include my name preceded by @.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look in /var/log/cron for jobs that run at that time of day

Perhaps the system is doing something else that exhausts memory

if you cannot stop the cronjob from running that causes the problem then
either alter the instance size to add more memory or add a swapfile

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-memory-swap-file/